# What is the difference between maintenance and standby in pacemaker

Tags: pacemaker

In pacemaker there is a *standby* mode. From what I understand, it will cause active services to be migrated away from that node in order to do maintenance on it. 
However there is also a *maintenance* mode or flag which I cannot seem to find any reasonable documentation for. 
This leads me to my question: Can anyone enlighten me as to what the differences between standby and maintenance are in pacemaker. Maybe even what their exact properties are.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Red Hat, being a major contributor of [pacemaker](https://clusterlabs.org/pacemaker/) (SUSE being another, from Clusterlabs' informations), provides quite good documentation about it.

---

### Standby mode

`standby` mode is for a *node* being a part of a cluster. Setting a node in standby mode will (attempt to) migrate services on other online nodes.

[4.4.5. Standby Mode](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/high_availability_add-on_reference/s1-clusternodemanage-haar#s2-standbymode-HAAR)

> The following command puts the specified node into standby mode. The specified node is no longer able to host resources.
> Any resources currently active on the node will be moved to another
> node. If you specify the --all, this command puts all nodes into
> standby mode.

To set a *node* in *standby* mode:

```
    pcs cluster standby <node>
```

---

### Maintenance mode

`maintenance-mode` is for the *whole cluster*. Setting the cluster in maintenance mode will make the cluster not attempt to manage services any more for whatever reason: the administrator of the cluster can now do actions without having the cluster interfering in any way.

[4.8. Cluster Maintenance](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/high_availability_add-on_reference/s1-clustermaint-haar)

> In order to perform maintenance on the nodes of your cluster, you may need to stop or move the resources and
> services running on that cluster. Or you may need to stop the cluster
> software while leaving the services untouched. Pacemaker provides a
> variety of methods for performing system maintenance.
> [...]
> If you
> need to put the cluster in a state where **no services will be started
> or stopped**, you can *set the maintenance-mode cluster property*. Putting
> the cluster into maintenance mode automatically unmanages all
> resources. For information on setting cluster properties, see Table
> [12.1, “Cluster Properties”](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/high_availability_add-on_reference/ch-clusteropts-haar#s1-clusterproperties-HAAR).

To set *the cluster* in maintenance mode:

```
pcs property set maintenance-mode=true
```

---

So for example, to compare two things which might appear similar: the main difference immediately visible between putting *all* nodes in standby mode, and putting *the cluster* in maintenance mode, is that for the former case, it will stop all services, since there's no online node any more, while for the later, services will stay as they were, started or not, on various nodes.

Comment: RedHat documentation - that obvious after all. Its actually quite a bit better than the "original" pacemaker documentation. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I see this is an old question... but I think I can add something to the good answer above.

My experience is mostly in SLES clusters. It is possible to put either a cluster OR a node into maintenance mode. Maintenance mode puts the resources on that node into "unmanaged" state ─ where the resources are no longer monitored by the cluster, and the cluster will not stop or start resources.
https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=000019250

The pacemaker documentation also looks good to me. Perhaps it has been updated since the question was asked.
https://clusterlabs.org/pacemaker/doc/en-US/Pacemaker/2.0/html-single/Pacemaker_Explained/index.html
Search in that page for "maintenance".